# Efficient replication of data in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data of the form

```
dates = as.Date(c("2015-04-07","2015-04-07","2015-04-08","2015-04-08"))
hour = rep(c(1,2),2)
value = c(3,6,8,4)
example.data = data.frame(dates,hour,value)
```

which gives

```
      dates hour value
1 2015-04-07    1     3
2 2015-04-07    2     6
3 2015-04-08    1     8
4 2015-04-08    2     4
```

and I would like to generate data for each quarter of an hour with constant fill-in.

The results should be

```
      dates hour  qhour value
1 2015-04-07    1   0     3
2 2015-04-07    1   1     3
3 2015-04-07    1   2     3
4 2015-04-07    1   3     3
5 2015-04-07    2   0     6
6 2015-04-07    2   1     6
7 2015-04-07    2   2     6
```

and so forth. Thus just replicating each value per hour for each quarter if an hour during this respective hour. Can this be done elegenantly using `sqldf` or something similar. Of course my data set if much much bigger than the example.

Comment: There is also a wrapper function for this in the `splitstackshape` package. Try `library(splitstackshape) ; expandRows(example.data, 4, count.is.col = FALSE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this sufficiently efficient?

```
DF <- example.data[rep(seq_len(nrow(example.data)), each = 4),]
DF$qhour <- 0:3
#         dates hour value qhour
#1   2015-04-07    1     3     0
#1.1 2015-04-07    1     3     1
#1.2 2015-04-07    1     3     2
#1.3 2015-04-07    1     3     3
#2   2015-04-07    2     6     0
#2.1 2015-04-07    2     6     1
#2.2 2015-04-07    2     6     2
#2.3 2015-04-07    2     6     3
#3   2015-04-08    1     8     0
#3.1 2015-04-08    1     8     1
#3.2 2015-04-08    1     8     2
#3.3 2015-04-08    1     8     3
#4   2015-04-08    2     4     0
#4.1 2015-04-08    2     4     1
#4.2 2015-04-08    2     4     2
#4.3 2015-04-08    2     4     3
```

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for.